# Is there a way to handle the payment in the Backend Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal

I made a website with react and i used "react-paypal-button-v2" package to integrate paypal to my website,
so everything is working well, but Now what i would like to do is to hide the " ClientId " which is one of the properties of react-paypal-button-v2 as below:

```
<PayPalButton
              amount={amount}
              currency={currency}
              onSuccess={(details, data) => onSuccess(details, data)}
              options={{
                clientId: "YOUR_CLINET_ID"
              }}
          />
```

because it is not secure to put sensitive data in the front-end as they said in the documentation [from react apps documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), so for that i decided to handle this on the backend and save the ClientId as a variable and use it each time request payment is fired.
so my question is what is the best way to make the payment on the server side?
or if I'm wrong and there is way better than this please tell me.
thank in advance guys.

Comment: similar concept is with Razorpay also but the client id is not sensitive information. you can go ahead and store it in your frontend configs

Comment: so it doesn't matter if someone got that client_id ?

Comment: yes it really doesn't matter because the main is secret key and you should store that secret key in backend that's all I have done the similar thing while intergrating Razorpay

Comment: ohkey thank you Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client ID is not sensitive information. It is intended to be used on the client side.

A server integration uses a client ID + secret for API calls. Server integrations are more robust and secure, so if you have the resources and ability to integrate with a backend it's recommended that you do so.

### Vanilla JS+backend approach

Create two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data. The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

### React specifics

react-paypal-button-v2 is not an official module, try the newer [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) instead.  See the "Docs" tab of [the Storybook.](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default)

Comment: Thank you so much Preston, this helps a lot.